# ios: scaling font horizontally without rasterising

Tags: ios, fonts, scale

Android provides a property `textScaleX`, that allows to scale text horizontally while retaining font height. I use it quite extensively for Android apps (especially for languages which are not as compact as English) and wish to find something similar in ios.

Obviously, I can draw a text to a graphic context and scale it as an image, but this seems to be a rather awkward solution which turns all text items into ImageView-s.

Is there a *native* way to scale text horizontally? For example there might be an option to create a custom font based on a system font and change a parameter responsible for text width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just scale the UILabel or UITextView that contains the text:

```
UILabel *label = ...
label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8,1); //reduced size in x direction by 20%
```

If that is not enough, you could look into NSLayoutManger, there may be something there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `matrix` attribute of `UIFontDescriptor`.

Here's an example that takes a `UILabel` in `self.label` and sets its font to be stretched horizontally by a factor of 1.3.

```
UIFont* baseFont = self.label.font;
UIFontDescriptor *baseDescriptor = baseFont.fontDescriptor;
UIFontDescriptor *newDescriptor = [baseDescriptor fontDescriptorWithMatrix:
    CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.0)];
UIFont* newFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:newDescriptor size:0.0];
self.label.font = newFont;
```

Comment: Thanks, Nils and Kurt. Both answers are useful. Nils's approach is simpler and closer to textScaleX idea. Kurt's solution allows to create one font for several views. Also (correct me if I'm wrong), when transformation is applied directly, the text is scaled while rendering, while  with a custom font the text is drawn pre-scaled, which makes it better looking. I accept Nil's answer for simplicity and +1 to Kurt for a great idea.